# can I make archive manager use 7z?

Tags: archive, rar

I'm on ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and having trouble extracting RAR 5 archives.
GNOME Archive Manager shows no files.
`unrar-free` doesn't work because it apparently supports RAR 2 only.
`p7zip` doesn't work either, it says unknown suffix.
`7z x asd.rar` works fine, but I was wondering if it is possible to integrate it with GNOME archive manager?

Comment: What do you mean by integrate it?

Comment: @David like, view and extract files by dragdropping. When I open a RAR5 archive with archive manager, it seems empty.

Comment: You are still not being clear drag drop into what? You need to add more info to the question with EDIT.

Comment: On GNOME Archive Manager, it's not possible to view/extract RAR5 files. With `unrar`, it's not possible to view/extract RAR5 files. With `7z` it's possible to extract and view RAR5 files. I was wondering, if GNOME Archive Manager is using `unrar` by default, is it possible to switch to `7z`, since it supports RAR5 files. editing to add more info

Comment: It is possible, but you'll need to patch it.

Comment: @Pilot6 ah, I see, thanks. is this a common problem in ubuntu/gnome archive manager? whenever I search for it, I can't find the same issue much, so idk if it's a "problem" in archive manager, or just my setup